# Warning: Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`Login`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Login`

Tags: reactjs

My problem here is, when the user is logged in, the login page can't be access because they are already logged in so i put an if statement, if the user is logged in, they will redirect to the homepage. Somehow it works but it console logs  warnings about browser routers.

**This is my App.jsx**

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [userCommerce, setUserCommerce] = useState(null);
  const getBool = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await instance.get("/isLoggedIn");
      console.log(result)
      setUserCommerce(result.data.user);
      setIsLoggedIn(result.data.isLoggedIn);
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  
  }
  useEffect( () => {
    getBool();
    console.log(isLoggedIn, userCommerce);
  }, [])
```

**This is my Login.jsx**

```
if (value.isLoggedIn) {
      return navigate("/home")
   }
    return(
        <div>
            // HTML FORM
        </div>
    )
```

If i remove the

```
if (value.isLoggedIn) {
      return navigate("/home")
}
```

It still works but they access the login page, but they should not because they are already logged in.

Comment: Have you considered putting the redirect logic into the react router instead?